# XQuery and XSLT are no use after Extension Class

Tags: class, wso2

I write a class mediator(AbstractMediator) to convert return code between client and service. 
My class mediator return message is :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body>0000</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

After this I need get the return code, and then use XSLT or XQuery construct response message.
But XSLT or XQuery is no use. It always return:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body>0000</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Why XSLT and XQuery is no use after extension class? How to convert return code? Anyone can help me?
Best regards.

Comment: There should be some problem in your code. The XSLT mediator itself extends the Abstract mediator and does the XSLT transformation. It would help if you post your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, there is no restriction to use XSLT or XQuery mediators after a class mediator. You can do transformations appropriately with a combination of these mediators. In your case you have to write an appropriate XSLT style sheet to transform the SOAP body content.